# Tela de splash scren React-native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Criei uma classe componente com a minha tela de `splash`. E quero que após alguns segundos, a navegação vai para a outra tela, já tenho configurado a navegação

```
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({   Home: {screen: BrunoDantas},  
  Chat: {screen: ChatScreen},
});
```

a classe da `sprint`, tentei o seguinte para ver se diretamente ja redirecionava:

```
render() {

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.logo}>
          <Image source={require('./img/logoimg.png')} style={styles.imglogo} />
          <Image source={require('./img/logonome.png')} style={styles.imgnome}  />
        </View>
      </View>

);

navigate('chat');   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primeira observação que faço é que, no seu código da classe `sprint` você chamou a função navigate('chat') após uma chamada de return(), o que fará com que navigate nunca seja chamada.

Uma solução modificando pouco o seu código seria deixar a sua função render desse jeito:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.logo}>
          <Image source={require('./img/logoimg.png')} style={styles.imglogo} />
          <Image source={require('./img/logonome.png')} style={styles.imgnome}  />
        </View>
      </View>

    );
}
```

E adicionando a na função componentDidMount() o seguinte:

```
componentDidMount(){
    setTimeOut(()=>{
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        navigate('chat');
    },2000)
}
```

Entretanto é importante ressaltar de que nunca é bom deixar o seu usuário esperando se não houver nada sendo processado em background, a splash screen é uma tela feita para deixar o seu usuário esperando **pelas requisições iniciais e outros carregamentos** que são feitos no momento que o seu aplicativo é iniciado. A melhor (e mais fácil de implementar) maneira de garantir que o seu usuário irá esperar somente o tempo necessário é utilizando do [react-native-smart-splash-screen](https://github.com/react-native-component/react-native-smart-splash-screen).

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @LeandroAyala se a resposta estiver correta e você conseguiu solucionar o seu problema, por favor, marque-a como certa !

Comment: Por favor corrija o nome da função setTimeout, se nao vai dar `setTimeOut is not defined`